# Как ограничить вращение камеры TrackballControls в three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Я использую вот такой код для ограничения вращения камеры

```
 var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls (camera, renderer.domElement);

 controls.maxAzimuthAngle = 0;
 controls.minAzimuthAngle = 0;
 controls.maxPolarAngle = 1.5708;  
 controls.minPolarAngle = 1.5708;
```

но он работает с OrbitControls а мне нужен TrackballControls

единственное что работает c TrackballControls это

```
controls.enabled = false ;
```

кто нибудь знает как ограничить вращение камеры в TrackballControls

Comment: Никак. Этот тип контролов не содержит свойств для ограничения вращения камеры.

Comment: @prisoner849 а можно ли как то изменить действие в OrbitControls на правую кнопку мыши как в TrackballControls. или назначить отдельную клавишу. Прост неудобно перемещаться по пространству лишь в одной плоскости top. [OrbitControls](http://static2.keep4u.ru/2019/01/08/orba382fdf6511049f0.gif) [TrackballControls](http://static2.keep4u.ru/2019/01/08/trak5849f1ad04c98f7b.gif) я просто не могу опустится ниже уровня пола.

Comment: У `THREE.OrbitControls()` есть свойство `.screenSpacePanning`, если оно установлено в `false`, то камера по правой кнопке мыши будет перемещаться в плоскости XZ, если установлено в `true` то перемещение будет осуществляться в координатах экрана (как есть).